# Facebook random error “An error occurred. Please try again later”

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

EDIT: It seems that I can only make 2  posts per day. If I remove the Logout step I can post as much as I want.

I've looked at many other “An error occurred. Please try again later” threads on here and haven't seen exactly my issue so I feel it does warrant its own thread.

I have an app thats sole purpose is to schedule and post messages to Facebook. This app has been working great. As flawless as a FB app can run. I was asked to force the user to relog in every post for security reasons so the first step is to use the javascript SDK to log the user out, then proceed to logging them in and prompting them for their information.

This also works, most of the time... For some unknown reason I randomly get the “An error occurred. Please try again later” page after I enter my FB login credentials.

So the flow is:

User configures the post.
User hits 'send now.'
We log the user out.
We attempt to authenticate the user.
The user is prompted by FB for their UN/PW.
The user submits this information.
“An error occurred. Please try again later”

Once this starts it continues until I give up. Trying again later does indeed eventually work however whatever is broken needs to be fixed.

It's important to note that there have been no code changes in the project at all between when it works and when it starts throwing the “An error occurred. Please try again later” error. The exact same code works for One, two or three posts and then FB decides it just wont let me do anything anymore.

I do notice that when it stops working it stops prepopulating my e-mail address when prompted to log in. However when it works it will prepopulate that field.

Has anyone seen what I've described?

Yes we have sandbox disabled.
Yes the domain matches up.
Everything is configured correctly enough that it works when it wants to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the problem was resulting from me being logged in to the main browser page but calling FB.logout() from a page within an iFrame.